# 403 error php apache laravel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

In logs I found next error:

```
[Thu Jun 01 14:40:44 2017] [error] [client 12.34.567.899] client denied by server configuration: /home/users/s/user123/domains/site.com/
```

I have 2 .htaccess files:

/domains/site.com/public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

/domains/site.com/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Why this error appears and how can I fix it?

The most strange thing is that this error appears randomly. I mean, in one moment site can stop responding and then, after few minutes continiue work well.

Comment: Did you've setup a custom [virtual host] configuration (e.g project.conf) for this as well?

Comment: I have a file web.config, here's content of it
https://pastebin.com/iQq3HVtE